# (FIXED) Blender 3.2.2 Desired material wouldn't apply, emission color shows up instead

Tags: texturing, materials

I tried giving this svg a metallic texture, i selected the svg and put metallic at 1.000, roughness at 0, switched the viewport shading to material preview and also tried the rendered preview it still wouldn’t show up as metallic and only showed the emission color, then i redid everything and switched to edit mode and selected everything with **A** then applied the material, still didn’t work. i’m sort of new to blender so i’m really sorry if i overlooked anything even though i feel like i’ve done everything by the book but still didn’t get the desired results, any help would be extremely appreciated.

[image]
metallic 1.000 , roughness 0.000 , emission strength 1.000

[image]
metallic 1.000 , roughness 0.000 , emission strength 1.000 (red)

[image]
metallic 0.000 , roughness 0.300 , emission strength 1.000

[image]
metallic 1.000 , roughness 0.000 , emission strength 0.000

**[FIXED!!]**
after contemplating abandoning the project i tried one last thing which was to uninstall blender(3.2.2) and re-install a previous version of blender(2.80.75) which worked!

get the msi file of either x64 or x32 windows depending on your system:
https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.80/

list of all the releases if someone wants to experiment further or attempt to find the most recent version that doesn't have the material problem:
https://download.blender.org/release/

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: of course @moonboots ! although blend-exchange wouldn't allow it, i've put it up on we transfer https://we.tl/t-ZjFiWmgwhT

Comment: It works fine in Material preview, in Rendered preview you need to reactivate Scene Lights and Scene World, it won't work fine because you don't have any HDRI image for the world for the moment. But it doesn't look black like in your first picture

Comment: i've added an HDRI and tried to apply the material to a sphere to see if the svg is the problem but they're both black, i'm guessing it has to be a hardware issue, thank you for checking though i really appreciate it @moonboots!

Comment: yes it may be a graphic card or driver issue? I hope someone will know...

Comment: @moonboots i fixed it somehow through installing a previous version of blender so it's confirmed that it has to be drivers or graphics card either way now it works, thanks again!

Comment: Oh ok i hope you'll find a solution

Comment: what does it give if you switch to a previous driver version? there are some problems with the last AMD driver. Also maybe try in the Render panel > Performance > High Quality Normals